# Input needing to be entered twice for my code to work

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to coding and have been assigned a class project, in this project to make a game I was trying to write a function that upon losing/dying the
`def playAgain():` function would ask the user if they want to play again.

```
from sys import exit
def playAgain():
print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
while True:
    if input("> ").lower().startswith('yes')== True:
        start()
    elif input("> ").lower().startswith('no')== True:
        print ('Bye for now')
        exit(0)
    else:
        print ("I don't understand what you mean?")
```

This function 'should' ask the user if they want to play again and depending on if yes or no was entered it would either go to the function `start()` or exit.

The issue is that when the input is entered the first time it is seemingly ignored in the code and must be entered a second time for any thing to happen in the code.

This has confused me a fair amount so any input on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Side note - this issue doesn't appear to happen when yes is entered first meaning this is probably an issue with the `elif` or `else` statements

Comment: Because you are calling `input` twice?

Comment: Also, `startswith` already returns a boolean, no need for`... == True`

Comment: Call `input` only once and store the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sys import exit

def playAgain():
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    while True:
        choice = input("> ")
        if choice.lower().startswith('yes'):
            start()
        elif choice.lower().startswith('no'):
            print ('Bye for now')
            exit(0)
        else:
            print ("I don't understand what you mean?")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write it as a function then really you should return a value upon which to base your next step.

```
def playAgain():
    while True:
        ans = input("Do you want to play again? (yes or no) ")
        if ans.lower().startswith('y'):
            return True
        elif ans.lower().startswith('n'):
            return False
        else:
            print ("I don't understand what you mean?")

def start():
    print ("game restarted")

if playAgain():
    start()
else:
    print ("Bye for now")
    quit()
```

Note that `startswith` allows you to check just `y` and `n` rather than the full words yes and no

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to assign a variable to the input and compare the variable as many times as you want.

```
from sys import exit 

def playAgain():
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')

    while True:
        inp = input("> ").lower()

        if inp.startswith('y'):
            start()
        elif inp.startswith('n'):
            print ('Bye for now')
            exit(0)
        else:
            print ("I don't understand, what do you mean?")
```